# display all available named scopes of a model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

Especially when you are using Searchlogic. It is kinda hard for me to guess what named scope to use to achieve what I need.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all defined named scopes for a model, using

```
Model.scopes
=> {:one_scope_name=>#<Proc:0x0000...>, :other_scope_name=>#<Proc:0x0000...>, ... }
```

It gives you a hash, so if you want only names, use `Model.scopes.keys`

But this will give you only scopes, that are already defined. It won't help you will scopes, generated by searchlogic, because, as you can read in [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/searchlogic) (Under the hood section), scopes like `field_eq` etc are created only when they are first used:

> Searchlogic utilizes method_missing
> to create all of these named scopes.
> When it hits method_missing it creates
> a named scope to ensure it will never
> hit method missing for that named
> scope again. Sort of a caching
> mechanism. It works in the same
> fashion as ActiveRecord's "`find_by_*`"
> methods. This way only the named
> scopes you need are created and
> nothing more.

Comment: Seems like this method is not longer available